# How to insert conditional rows in a panelGrid while keeping the rows succinct?

Tags: jsf

I have an `h:panelGrid` with two columns and various rows:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:outputLabel for="attr1" value="#{messages.attr1}" />
    <p:inputText id="attr1" value="#{viewBean.attr1}" />
    <p:outputLabel for="attr2" value="#{messages.attr2}" />
    <p:inputText id="attr2" value="#{viewBean.attr2}">
    <p:outputLabel for="attr3" value="#{messages.attr3}" />
    <p:inputText id="attr3" value="#{viewBean.attr3}" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

Now, some rows should only be present conditionally. In the example this could be the attr2 and attr3. When I build an `<ui:fragment />` around them the conditional rendering works (see below), however jsf tries to put the whole block into one `<td />` table cell element.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:outputLabel for="attr1" value="#{messages.attr1}" />
    <p:inputText id="attr1" value="#{viewBean.attr1}" />
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{viewBean.myCondition}">
        <p:outputLabel for="attr2" value="#{messages.attr2}" />
        <p:inputText id="attr2" value="#{viewBean.attr2}">
        <p:outputLabel for="attr3" value="#{messages.attr3}" />
        <p:inputText id="attr3" value="#{viewBean.attr3}" />
    </ui:fragment>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Another option would be to create two panelGrids. One for the first block and one for the second block:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <p:outputLabel for="attr1" value="#{messages.attr1}" />
    <p:inputText id="attr1" value="#{viewBean.attr1}" />
</h:panelGrid>
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{viewBean.myCondition}">
        <p:outputLabel for="attr2" value="#{messages.attr2}" />
        <p:inputText id="attr2" value="#{viewBean.attr2}">
        <p:outputLabel for="attr3" value="#{messages.attr3}" />
        <p:inputText id="attr3" value="#{viewBean.attr3}" />
    </ui:fragment>
</h:panelGrid>
```

The problem here is that the columns are now not succinct anymore across both grids. What could be a solution to circumvent this issue?

Note, that I have more than just three rows so putting a `rendered` attribute for each `outputLabel` and `inputText` element would be quite tedious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`<h:panelGrid>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/panelGrid.html) renderer only considers **direct** `UIComponent` children as table cells, not the deeper nested ones. The `<ui:fragment>` is actually also an `UIComponent`. Hence it becomes a single table cell with all of its nested children enclosed.

You have 2 options, depending on the source of the `rendered` condition:

1. If it's available during view build time, use `<c:if>` instead.

   ```
   <h:panelGrid columns="2">
       <p:outputLabel ... />
       <p:inputText ... />
       <c:if test="#{viewBean.myCondition}">
           <p:outputLabel ... />
           <p:inputText ... />
           <p:outputLabel ... />
           <p:inputText ... />
       </c:if>
   </h:panelGrid>
   ```
2. Otherwise, if it's not guaranteed to be available during view build time, get rid of `<ui:fragment>` and repeat the `rendered` condition over the children.

   ```
   <h:panelGrid columns="2">
       <p:outputLabel ... />
       <p:inputText ... />
       <p:outputLabel ... rendered="#{viewBean.myCondition}" />
       <p:inputText ... rendered="#{viewBean.myCondition}" />
       <p:outputLabel ... rendered="#{viewBean.myCondition}" />
       <p:inputText ... rendered="#{viewBean.myCondition}" />
   </h:panelGrid>
   ```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes)